# Get count of child nodes under each node of a tree

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, tree

I am making a tree from json data :

```
{
   "text":{
      "name":"test41 (3256)",
      "balance":"Total Balance: 0",
      "profit":"Total Profit: 0"
   },
   "image":"treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg",
   "id":"3256",
   "parentId":"3243",
   "children":[
      {
         "text":{
            "name":"test45 (3261)",
            "balance":"Total Balance: 0",
            "profit":"Total Profit: 0"
         },
         "image":"treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg",
         "id":"3261",
         "parentId":"3256"
      },
      {
         "text":{
            "name":"test46 (3262)",
            "balance":"Total Balance: 0",
            "profit":"Total Profit: 0"
         },
         "image":"treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg",
         "id":"3262",
         "parentId":"3256",
         "children":[
            {
               "text":{
                  "name":"test51 (3267)",
                  "balance":"Total Balance: 0",
                  "profit":"Total Profit: 0"
               },
               "image":"treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg",
               "id":"3267",
               "parentId":"3262"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":{
            "name":"test47 (3263)",
            "balance":"Total Balance: 0",
            "profit":"Total Profit: 0"
         },
         "image":"treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg",
         "id":"3263",
         "parentId":"3256"
      }
   ]
}
```

and the tree made from this data looks like below (I am using treant.js library to make tree);

[image]

Now, I want to display number of child nodes below every node. So, I want a logic that can calculate number of child nodes of every node and amend its value in every nodes "text" parameter in array data. Array of the above tree looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => Array ( [name] => test41 (3256) [balance] => Total Balance: 0 [profit] => Total Profit: 0 ) [image] => treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg [id] => 3256 [parentId] => 3243 [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => Array ( [name] => test45 (3261) [balance] => Total Balance: 0 [profit] => Total Profit: 0 ) [image] => treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg [id] => 3261 [parentId] => 3256 ) [1] => Array ( [text] => Array ( [name] => test46 (3262) [balance] => Total Balance: 0 [profit] => Total Profit: 0 ) [image] => treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg [id] => 3262 [parentId] => 3256 [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => Array ( [name] => test51 (3267) [balance] => Total Balance: 0 [profit] => Total Profit: 0 ) [image] => treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg [id] => 3267 [parentId] => 3262 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [text] => Array ( [name] => test47 (3263) [balance] => Total Balance: 0 [profit] => Total Profit: 0 ) [image] => treant-js-master/images/1621593159.jpg [id] => 3263 [parentId] => 3256 ) ) ) )
```

Help me build a logic that can parse this array, calculate child nodes of every node and amend the "text" parameter with [count] of child nodes.

Comment: You need to use DFS (Depth First Search) to count the child nodes and then backtrack it to parent node and assign the count.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your best attempt (code). What does not work as expected? Please read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Comment: are you trying to implement this logic in PHP or javascript? Also, have you made any attempt at it?